# Loop through foreach and put elements from that foreach into a new multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach that is looping over an array as it's supposed to, and then I'm pulling information out of that array from the foreach.  I need to put this information into a separate empty array. I've got working, kind of. Here's my code:

```
newArray = array();
foreach ($result as $value) {
    newArray[] = $value['sample1'];
    newArray[] = $value['sample2'];
    newArray[] = $value['sample3'];
}
print_r(newArray);
```

This prints an associative array that looks like:

```
{
    0: "1",
    1: "1",
    2: "blah",
    3: "etc through as many values as I have",
}
```

Instead I need to have it form an array that looks like:

```
{
    0: {
        0: "1",
        1: "1",
        2: "blah"
    },
    1: {
        0: "etc"
    }
}
```

Any recommendations on how I should go about creating the new multidimensional array?

Comment: You only show an array assignment, but say "This prints". That's a mighty impressive trick.

Comment: O sorry I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a temp array containing the parts of the original you want, then add that temporary array to newArray like this

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $t = [ $value['sample1'], $value['sample2'], $value['sample3'] ];
    $newArray[] = $t;
}
```

Or is you are using an old PHP

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $t = array( $value['sample1'], $value['sample2'], $value['sample3'] );
    $newArray[] = $t;
}
```

OR shorthand

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $newArray[] = [ $value['sample1'], $value['sample2'], $value['sample3'] ];
}
```

and old PHP

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $newArray[] = array( $value['sample1'], $value['sample2'], $value['sample3'] );
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! I used the shorthand version but thank you for showing all of the options.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$newArray[]` you create a new item in the array every time.
You can try this instead:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key][] = $value['sample1'];
    $newArray[$key][] = $value['sample2'];
    $newArray[$key][] = $value['sample3'];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $newArray[] = [
      $value['sample1'],
      $value['sample2'],
      $value['sample3']
    ];
}
```